# no logro acceder a las variables de latitud y longitud

Tags: reactjs

Estoy desarrollando una app del clima con reactjs mediante llamadas a la api **openweathermap**. La llamada a la url current weather funciona bien y mediante el formulario obtengo todos los datos de la ciudad introducida, lo que no logro es extraer los datos de la segunda url que da el tiempo por horas, no logro acceder a la const `data` que me daría la longitud y latitud  de la ciudad que son los parametros que necesita la url del tiempo por horas, tampoco se muy bien si estoy llamando a la función `hoursData` en el lugar correcto. Estoy un poco perdido como podeis ver en el codigo, cualquier ayuda os lo agradecería mucho.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { AiOutlineMenu } from 'react-icons/ai';
import DisplayWeather from './DisplayWeather';
import DisplayWeatherHours from './DisplayWeatherHours';



function Weather() {

    const APIKEY = 'token';
    const URL_BASE = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/`;
    
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        city:"",
        country:"",

    })
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
    const [weatherhours, setWeathersHours] = useState([]);
    
    async function weatherData(e){
         
        
        e.preventDefault();
        
        if(form.city === ""){
            alert("Add country")
        }else{
             const data = await fetch(`${URL_BASE}weather?q=${form.city},${form.country}&appid=${APIKEY}`
            )
             .then((res) => res.json())
             .then((data) => data);
             

            setWeather(
                {
                    data: data
                }
            );
        }
    }
    

    async function hoursData(){
        let lat = data.coord.lat;
         let lon = data.coord.lon;
        const  hours = await fetch(`${URL_BASE}onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${APIKEY}`
         )
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((hours) => hours);

         setWeathersHours(
             {
                 hours: hours
             }
         );
        }
    
    
    
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        let name = e.target.name;
        let value = e.target.value;
    
        if(name === "country"){
            setForm({...form, city:value})
        }
        if(name === "city"){
            setForm({...form, city:value})
        }
        console.log(form.country, form.city)
    };

    return (
        <div className="cont">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="text_container">
                
                  <div className="btn-group dropleft">
                        <a className="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <AiOutlineMenu className="svg" height="30px" width="30px" />
                        </a>

                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                        
                            <form>
                            <input className="input1" type="text" name="country" placeholder="country..." onChange={e => handleChange(e)}/>
                            <input className="input2" type="text" name="city" placeholder="city..." onChange={e => handleChange(e)}/>
                            <div className="cont-btn">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={(e)=> weatherData(e)}>submit</button>
                            </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    {
                        weather.data !=undefined ? (
                        <div>
                             <DisplayWeather data={weather.data}/>
                        </div>
                        ) : null
                    }
                    <div>
                    <h1>
                        per hours
                    </h1>
                    <div>
                        
                            <div>
                            <DisplayWeatherHours hoursData={hoursData} data={weatherhours.hours} />
                            </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                   
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>   
        
    )

}
export default Weather;
```

Comment: Tienes que usar un hook que se ocupe de almacenar la data, por otra parte cambia tu key porque ya la hiciste publica y cualquier persona la puede usar.

Comment: No se exactamente que hace la funcion hoursData entonces no te puedo ayudar con eso.